# phpseclib3 encrypt got LengthException: Message too long

Tags: php, encryption, phpseclib

I have more than 2500 characters in a single JSON file and I want to encrypt the content using RSA in `phpseclib3` library but then it shows `Fatal error: Uncaught LengthException: Message too long in C:\xampp\htdocs\chamilo-1.11\vendor\phpseclib\phpseclib\phpseclib\Crypt\RSA\PublicKey.php on line 389` message.

From the code above, I kind of understand that the maximum length is `$keyLength - 2 * $hashLength -2` (while my key size is 2048) and I think increasing the key size is not reliable because the text the file content is dynamic and I can't predict the exact number.

Here's my code to do the encryption:

```php
<?php
require_once './vendor/autoload.php';
use phpseclib3\Crypt\RSA;

$publicKey = RSA::load("<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>wb4VVQwvfEtXlD3MKQF9320ltOS6/IbSXntFt8rcKiO/1xfO7a8wDFqMny57Xpokq+ROMXapCkAUictZf0e4cmXHaEwSbdUIeDxvYU4eSuhTAR9kaV3jilmheFyyAhfvkF0goz1YY/ulU/ATNXXqrTSa+bLTdwjyUI+naxyx+w9Y52vMHe52ZUv6JnVIjER0NBLQO9nvEHXJizHrWqErubdXN9DDvRygtuyrW4GEV0CHjayckl7YIhtY0LuYDd3d9qMn4ZzBpBOfPNP2cMhfw4Lc/hd3WrkjCAb7FDPQmW4LynEskoBsdRZsx/NhDMDqUPuyi5IQcEqXxid8C7D0AQ==</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent><P>+2vVwjUKJKgqLFSbWzlv7yHoz6PSoZZuBbAuP1fkjVdDartNcGEa/vblG3OSMciJEJ7Uxf2u+U6WtwIDZPJoiMVtTSSfwNv0SjLQzumngdfB46z/o2ZsQBcYeko+G51bawxfjJH0MtqNPMzB1okGDNqg+ANKEvuWHI5Zoo+CtXc=</P><Q>xUVXVd+TGzSlxUVBzUa9maTz2k+opuzA/7sFnUUu2JuSgDw11r4hEINhUEZDKJPgCwiP51ujbHFenv86vreBc4zoGp8tcf5Qe4uD0i/7o9KwqUJrHLxzH7tQTykh2V6R+/IcmL7jMND3XuACjalPit+TFAH+qvt4A70C0YG8YEc=</Q><DP>EJiPpaAmqUDId+Cl2KGz987/NSWVM8FgRdPZWakNlx7ZfmQaun5Ob+IQQX2hetPH6GbzmJYkRKShYjcpzjIKIG0Xx+3Q9cQPHg64pc/alMGPNN4oibqrDpf3r6rS6rO6YxiP/hFsUycGB6tkaCrnUVXlJjnhW9trjzr+Q7LBaAU=</DP><DQ>gpnRpCyMO6qzRNMBKWH4DExElPe/9CMx8xxiLyiqRwVYDEXQbwcY5NHWD0s1Exwza5qTitwEabr0pdbbkX/z2AglcdqIP7valLBc6T6THnZSNvyd5TxuC0f7dy0IF9ygUWiMviNCTgNKgilUB21cF9jEiq53Z8NsRS1RPFrj1+k=</DQ><InverseQ>QBnUSbXBRzjejeCXc8D4RFym576G9mFyQKXEoCUKL8+keAJN/8zD9wX99I1lt8OsLIgr1ToNT8AuA0D3PsO3nxlbq70MF0bjoDqoN2mM4mQmcjsS78rdwiHaXfj6XZYdGuJ6r6dfiBAUqWKfrQL8FRqdsQhtMmELEKs0lNOYrMk=</InverseQ><D>BGAOi0UjLWNmLurWWXa3KPyGBXfE4T8KMSgHgwcJwcnc4zaeba+vHhhNZKrgDlrcyST2vxc26gxYamQ1OTKdb7fssOZG5EQTVOPIgCILfRWSCkxzMA32vYEYrGcrffCccF4qBoW0IU3lhee+B08KZa7ycQEg1WdWUYts9HZJbqn37gGsfyleWeazKrmkv6Ek3+qBItFAYaBffXl3S8CP3tXoY+tcDRStMvluJnCE4i1LOoAVXuxxCNZi6dyjbD5tshAvbnzpdJU/RCQMAVPN5BMCO9KasKAyUFuqMz+VjhEBp7l42HrAwAyS9FIzU5to2g7YK+AsBKDg8dzz6Sv5IQ==</D></RSAKeyValue>");

$publicKey->encrypt(json_encode($array));
```

Is there any workaround to solve this?

Comment: RSA can only be used to encrypt plaintexts whose length is at most equal to the key size (here 2048 bits = 256 bytes) *minus* the space required for padding. For longer plaintexts, symmetric encryption (e.g. AES) is required, alone or in combination with asymmetric encryption (hybrid encryption).

Comment: @Topaco so my case is not solvable using RSA and the alternative is symmetric encryption like AES?

Comment: Yes, either symmetric encryption, e.g. AES, or [hybrid encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem).

Comment: @Topaco I see. Thanks!

Comment: https://phpseclib.com/docs/rsa#encryption--decryption talks about the maximum supported lengths for each encryption mode for RSA. No need to look at the code!

Comment: @neubert [I've created a table on Cryptography](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/42100/1172); RSA plaintext sizes are not language specific - it only depends on the hash function used. For RSA using PKCS#1 padding the minimum *official* overhead is 11 bytes, 8 bytes which are random values in the range [1, 256). However, you're better off using at least 16 bytes of randomness, so that would mean 19 bytes of overhead (to be subtracted from the key size in bytes).